# Dynamic IP resolve to Hostname-CentOS

Tags: networking, centos, hosts, hosts-file, hostname

I'm trying o figure out a way to create a hostname that resolves to a dynamic IP? To clarify, in a OS such as CentOS there is a hostfile that stores the hostname (host.local) and a associated static IP.

Well I need that IP in the host file to be dynamic. Not possible? Thats fine, is there a script of program I can use?

Again, can I resolve a local hostname to a dynamic IP in centos?

Comment: If it's strictly a local IP, why does it _have_ to be dynamic? On a local network the assumption is that you have some control, so the situation where you would need to update a hostname to a constantly changing IP probably rarely happens. On the Internet it happens all the time, which is why there are services for it. I guess assuming all info necessary is already in your question, the solution would be to set up your own DNS server and make sure the client reports to that server every time its IP changes.

Comment: Well its essentially a plug and play web server(my project) is what I am trying to accomplish. The user plugs the device in, goes to their browser and hits dynamicip.local( hostname example). So the end user would not edit the host file nor connect to dns server.